# random number generator and seed

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, openssl

I'm working with openssl cryptographic libraries, I'm new to all these cryptographic stuffs and slowly I'm learning all these. I have a doubt regarding random number generator, I'm using `RAND_pseudo_bytes()` for generating a pseudo random number. I'm providing a seed to it with my required entropy. But my doubt is if we provide same seed twice, will the random number generator generate the same random number ?

Comment: **Yes.** Hence the name *pseudo*-random generator. You should read your entropy (ie. your seed) from `/dev/urandom` if working on *nix. See [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/29321) for more.

Comment: rath, can you expand your comment a little bit and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend against using `RAND_pseudo_bytes()`. OpenSSL's CPRNG does not provide better pseudo-random numbers than /dev/urandom but it is much harder to use right. It has a couple of known flaws, for example it doesn't handle fork() very well. The standard PRNG is not very well designed, too. The FIPS mode PRNG is a bit better, though.

`/dev/urandom` (Linux, BSD, Solaris) are about as fast as `RAND_pseudo_bytes()`. You don't have to take care of seeding, fork hooks, thread locks and other stuff that makes the PRNG hard to use. You can just read as many bytes from `/dev/urandom` as you need. Windows has `CryptGenRandom()`.

No matter what some people or documents say: ignore `/dev/random`. `/dev/urandom` is fine for everything you are going to do.

Comment: I think saying _"No matter what some people or documents say: ignore `/dev/random`."_ is a pretty bald statement, especially considering you do not provide argumentation.